# Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \ ) at newpackage.Myclass.main(Myclass.java:8)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, geckodriver

I am working basic test script on selenium-cucumber and while executing I got this error -

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \ ) at newpackage.Myclass.main(Myclass.java:8).

```
public class Myclass { public static void main(String[] args){
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\User\karokiaswamy\downloads\geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64\geckodriver.exe");
driver.get("http://Application URL/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='siteLoginTab']/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input" )).sendKeys("Username");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='siteLoginTab']/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input" )).sendKeys("Password");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='siteLoginTab']/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/button")).click(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only place that I see backslashes is when you are defining where the driver is.

I would try this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/User/karokiaswamy/downloads/geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64/geckodriver.exe");
```

**EDIT**

So turns out that your code was edited by the person who formatted your code.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\User\\karokiaswamy\\downloads\\geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
```

If the error persists then we will have to see more of the code. In essence, the error is telling you that somewhere, you have a backslash that does not belong, and it's escaping a character that is not in the list it's shown you.

Comment: @ Kyle Fairns - Same  error message displaying after replacing the Forward slash.

Comment: Then I'm just as confused as you are, because there aren't any more escape characters in your code.

Comment: @ Kyle Fairns - I have edited the code, please check - ak nathan

Comment: If you do double backslashes for the Path (2nd parameter of System.setProperty(), your code should in theory work

Comment: @ Kyle Fairns - No didnot work after giving double backslashes also System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue of espace sequence

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class LaunchFirefox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\Downloads\Selenium\Selenium_setup\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\geckodriver.exe");
    }

}
```